# While in a transaction, how can reads to an affected row be prevented until the transaction is done?

Tags: mysql, transactions

I'm fairly sure this has a simple solution, but I haven't been able to find it so far. Provided an InnoDB MySQL database with the isolation level set to SERIALIZABLE, and given the following operation:

```
BEGIN WORK;
SELECT * FROM users WHERE userID=1;
UPDATE users SET credits=100 WHERE userID=1;
COMMIT;
```

I would like to make sure that as soon as the select inside the transaction is issued, the row corresponding to userID=1 is locked for *reads* until the transaction is done. As it stands now, UPDATEs to this row will wait for the transaction to be finished if it is in process, but SELECTs simply will read the previous value. I understand this is the expected behaviour in this case, but I wonder if there is a way to lock the row in such a way that SELECTs will also wait until the transaction is finished to return the values?

The reason I'm looking for that is that at some point, and with enough concurrent users, it could happen that while the previous transaction is in process someone else reads the "credits" to calculate something else. Ideally the code run by that someone else should wait for the transaction to finish to use the new value, because otherwise it could lead to irreversible desync issues.

Note that I don't want to lock the entire table for reads, just the specific row.

Also, I could add a boolean "locked" field to the tables and set it to 1 every time I'm starting a transaction but I don't really feel this is the most elegant solution here, unless there is absolutely no other way to handle this through mysql directly.

Comment: You could put a snapshot of your table into a temporary table:  `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t_users SELECT * FROM users;`.

Comment: That wouldn't do it, I want to make sure that reads to the specific row are denied while a transaction is in progress, creating a temporary table would only help if I were to remove the row from the main table and reinsert it back after I'm done, but that sounds like too many trips to the DB.

Comment: My bad, I had misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a workaround, specifically:

> SELECT ... LOCK IN SHARE MODE sets a shared mode lock on the rows
>   read. A shared mode lock enables other sessions to read the rows but
>   not to modify them. **The rows read are the latest available, so if they
>   belong to another transaction that has not yet committed, the read
>   blocks until that transaction ends.**

([Source](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-locking-reads.html))

It seems that one can just include LOCK IN SHARE MODE in the critical SELECT statements that rely on transactional data and they will indeed wait for current transactions to finish before retrieving the row/s. For this to work the transaction has to use FOR UPDATE explicitly (as opposed to the original example I gave). E.g., given the following:

```
BEGIN WORK;
SELECT * FROM users WHERE userID=1 FOR UPDATE;
UPDATE users SET credits=100 WHERE userID=1;
COMMIT;
```

Anywhere else in the code I could use:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE userID=1 LOCK IN SHARE MODE;
```

Since this statement is not wrapped in a transaction, the lock is released immediately, thus having no impacts in subsequent queries, but if the row involving userID=1 has been selected for update within a transaction this statement would wait until the transaction is done, which is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You could try the *SELECT ... FOR UPDATE* locking read.

*A SELECT ... FOR UPDATE reads the latest available data, setting exclusive locks on each row it reads. Thus, it sets the same locks a searched SQL UPDATE would set on the rows.*

Please go through the following site: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-locking-reads.html

Comment: Already tried but it only locks the row for writes, not reads; plus I believe it makes no difference if the isolation level is already set to SERIALIZE.

Comment: (I can't edit the previous comment for some reason but I obviously meant SERIALIZABLE there)

Comment: Upvoted though because it did help to find a workaround (see original post)